# Modal will not display, but the app is not displaying any errors

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I am currently learning React and I am trying to create a simple modal that will display when the page loads. When I saved the changes, the page went to white and there aren't any errors in the console. I set the state to true and then tried calling it up in the render, thinking that this could be a way to do it. Can someone tell me what is it that I am doing wrong?

Modal.js

```
import React from 'react';


class Modal extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {open:true}
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div open={this.state.open}>
                <p>Hello</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Modal;
```

How I imported it into my app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage'
import DadJokesApi from './components/DadJokesApi'
import SportsJokesApi from './components/SportsJokesApi'
import ProgrammingJokesApi from './components/ProgrammingJokesApi';
import { Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Modal from './components/Modal';

function App() {
  return (
      <main>
        <Modal />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/DadJokes" component={DadJokesApi} />
          <Route path="/SportsJokes" component={SportsJokesApi} />
          <Route path="/ProgrammingJokes" component={ProgrammingJokesApi} />
          <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
      </main>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you put your code in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)/codepen?

Comment: You can have a quick view of other libs' modal component for an understanding of what kind of shape it should be https://material-ui.com/components/modal/

Comment: And there is not such prop `open` on `div`, it is pretty useless

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix few issues in your code:

- you are missing wrap your `Routes` with `Router`
- the `div` has `open` prop which is not required

I have taken your code and made it work basic way. Go thru it and leave a comment for further doubts and I will edit my answer.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-frost-1hj6r?file=/src/App.js

Also, in your case, try to to maintain a state called `open` in your parent (eg: `App.js`) and pass it to your `Modal` component. In your app.js you can decide and turn the state `open` to off/on based on your loading condition.